# Problems trying to use Flowplayer as flash fallback to html5 video

Tags: flash, html, video, flowplayer

I've now successfully managed to get html5 video tags to work and I'm now trying to implement a flash fallback solution using Flowplayer.  Below is my code:-

```
<div id="videocontent">
            <video width="640" height="360" autobuffer controls preload="auto" >
              <source src="fracWelDay3.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
              <source src="fracWelDay3.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
              <source src="fracWelDay3.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" width="640" height="360">
                <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">    
                <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/fracWelDay3.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
             </object>
          </video>
    </div>
```

This is the link to the video:

```
http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/day3FracWelVideo.html
```

In order to test this in Firefox, I commented out the line which referenced the .ogv file.(The commenting doesn't show here. When I included it here on this page, the text below the commenting disappeared) However, when I test it in Firefox, I just get a grey box. I would be very grateful if someone could help.

Many thanks, Pippa

Thanks, but I'm still really stuck.  I downloaded VideoJs and implemented, (I think accordingly).  `Below is my code:-

```
<script src="video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

// Add VideoJS to all video tags on the page when the DOM is ready
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();

```
            <div id="videocontent">
        <div class="video-js-box">
            <video width="640" height="360" preload="" controls="" poster="day3Wel.jpg" class="video-js" tabindex="0" >
              <source src="fracWelDay3.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
              <source src="fracWelDay3.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
              <source src="fracWelDay3.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" width="640" height="360" class="vjs-flash-fallback">
                <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">    
                <param value="config={'clip':{'url':'fracWelDay3.mp4','autoPlay':false,'autoBuffering':true, 'scaling':'orig'}}" name="flashvars">
                <!-- Image Fallback -->
                <img width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities." alt="Poster Image" src="day3Wel.jpg">
               </object>
          </video>
        </div> 
        </div>
```

The Flowplayer seems to load, but I get an error message saying that the video clip won't load and I don't know why.  Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

on the object... place an id.. that is one of the things i realized with flowplyer..
most probably you have the 2124 error.. unable to load resource.. right??

..........
...

that should do the trick..

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [videoJS](http://videojs.com/) to solve problems like yours. This is example of code:

```
<script src="/images/js/zencoder/video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/images/js/zencoder/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS" charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        VideoJS.setup();
}
</script>
<div class="video-js-box">
    <video width="480" height="272" preload="" controls="" poster="/images/video/videoBackMiddle.png" class="video-js" tabindex="0">
        <source type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' src="/images/video/01.mov"></source>
        <!--Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
          <object width="480" height="272" data="/images/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="vjs-flash-fallback">
            <param value="/images/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" name="movie">
            <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
            <param value="config={'clip':{'url':'/images/video/01.mov','autoPlay':false,'autoBuffering':true, 'scaling':'orig'}}" name="flashvars">
            <!-- Image Fallback -->
            <img width="480" height="272" title="No video playback capabilities." alt="Poster Image" src="/images/video/videoBackMiddle.jpg">
          </object>
        </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I changed all the links to absolute links hoping that might make a difference.  Flowplayer seems to load, but the video still doesn't load.  The link to the file is: [link](http://www.synergese.co.uk/testMathsOnline/day3/videos/day3FracWelVideo.html)